# Repeatable crash on iOS app v1.1.0.90 when tapping on questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Open the feed on the iOS app v 1.1.0.90 and tap any question (the blog post and things that open in an external browser are safe). I'm on an iPhone 5 iOS 7.1.2 (11D257).

App crashes on me every time. SIGABRT in the log on thread 0 with 0

Let me know if you'd like the text of the crash reports or a specific item if the crash is not obvious to the developers. I'm also getting the crash in any of the main browsing windows when tapping on a specific question.

Oddly, going in through the achievements, I can view questions from that avenue, but the majority of the app causes crashes when looking at questions on the half dozen of sites I've checked before submitting this bug report.

Comment: Ugh. I'll fix it when I get home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException**
>
> cell reuse indentifier in nib (SEQuestionTableViewCell) does not match the identifier used to register the nib (SELoadingTableViewCell)

Apple does this thing where when you assign UI to a reuse identifier, it does a sanity check against a field in the UI to make sure they match. **But the only do this on a device but not in the simulator.**  Not sure if this is a conspiracy to get everyone to use storyboards or a conspiracy to get everyone to sign up for a developer license, but it really burns developers who are too lazy to connect their phones to their laptops.

You should be getting a popup for 1.1.0.91 now.  The good news is that this puts me in second place for most crashes caused in the beta channel in a single day.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid patch and explanation. Excellent work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet of one crash...

```
Identifier: com.stackexchange.ent.zaphod
Version: 1.1.0.90 (1.1.0)
Code Type: ARM (Native)
Parent Process: launchd [1]
Date/Time: 2014-07-16 15:14:43.525 -0500
OS Version: iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)
Report Version: 104
Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread: 0
Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x2e61cec6 0x38db7ce2 0x2e61cd98 0x2efcae2a 0x30f8156a 0x2c6c75e 0x30fba614 0x2c6c80a 0x95486 0xe6dcc 0x13606c 0x30f81174 0x30f283d6 0x30f27c2c 0x30e4e2e0 0x30aca316 0x30ac5b3a 0x30e6347c 0xfea6a 0xfdbee 0x30e52a2e 0x30e527ec 0x30fdebee 0x30efc46a 0x30efc274 0x30efc20c 0x2ca7ad2 0x30e4e2e0 0x30aca316 0x30ac5b3a 0x30ac59cc 0x30ac53e0 0x30ac51f2 0x30e5199a 0x2e5e7faa 0x2e5e7472 0x2e5e5c62 0x2e550724 0x2e550506 0x334bf6ce 0x30eb186c 0x9555e 0x392b5ab2)
Thread 0 Crashed:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3936b6d8 0x39359000 + 75480
1 Stack Exchange 0x001d7a04 0x66000 + 1513988
2 libsystem_platform.dylib 0x393cf720 0x393cc000 + 14112
3 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x393d47b2 0x393d1000 + 14258
4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3931cff4 0x392d3000 + 303092
5 libc++abi.dylib 0x3876b98a 0x3876b000 + 2442
6 libc++abi.dylib 0x387846e2 0x3876b000 + 104162
7 libobjc.A.dylib 0x38db7f7a 0x38db4000 + 16250
8 libc++abi.dylib 0x387821b0 0x3876b000 + 94640
9 libc++abi.dylib 0x38781d12 0x3876b000 + 93458
10 libobjc.A.dylib 0x38db7e2a 0x38db4000 + 15914
11 CoreFoundation 0x2e55079a 0x2e548000 + 34714
12 CoreFoundation 0x2e550506 0x2e548000 + 34054
13 GraphicsServices 0x334bf6ce 0x334b6000 + 38606
14 UIKit 0x30eb186c 0x30e43000 + 452716
15 Stack Exchange 0x0009555e 0x66000 + 193886
16 libdyld.dylib 0x392b5ab4 0x392b4000 + 6836
```